# Why is my for loop cutting short - derivatives of functions

Tags: python, loops

Thanks for checking out my question. I have written a function

```
def find_term_derivative(term):
    x , y = term
    new_term = (y*x, y-1)
    return new_term
```

which essentially uses the power rule to find a derivative of a specific term, so when I want to find derivative of x^3, 
input is (1, 3)
output is (3, 2) indicating 3x^2.

I want to apply this to a multi-termed function, for example 4x^3-3x
to return 12x^2-3

Input is `[(4, 3), (-3, 1)]`
Output should read: `[(12, 2), (-3, 0)]`

My function is only returning the first term, and I am wondering if someone could help explain why?

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):

    for term in function_terms:
        new_function = []
        new_term = find_term_derivative(term)
        new_function.append(new_term)
        return new_function
```

Comment: your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop. you should dedent (or what is the opposite of **in**dent?) it by one level...

Comment: `return` immediately exits the function. Your for loop never gets to iterate a second time because a `return` is encountered.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies. When I unindent (dedent??) my return, my function then only returns the second term. Any ideas?

Comment: same thing, try to follow the flow of the loop. in each pass, you emptied out the previous outputs by writing `new_function = []`. That should also be happening outside the loop so that it only runs once before doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks paritosh! good spot, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_derivative(function_terms):
    new_function = []
    for term in function_terms:
        new_term = find_term_derivative(term)
        new_function.append(new_term)
    return new_function
```

Since you are returning inside forloop, your function is returning the first term.